# How to replace string in Eclipse with newline in replacement

Tags: java, eclipse

Of course this question can be googled - however most of the hits are very old and don't seem to apply in Eclipse Mars.

I simply want to replace a line with a multiline replacement.  There must be some way to do this, but I can't seem to find anything that works.

replace

```
import a.b.c.d;
```

with

```
import e.f.g.h;
import i.j.k.l;
```

Comment: Have you considered replacing with single-line `import e.f.g.h; import i.j.k.l;` and then running the code formatter?

Comment: No, but the answer is simply to do a regular expression search and then replacing with \n.

Answer (score 9):

First you need check "Regular expressions"
Then simply add \R between line.
For example 
Ctrl+F, select "Regular expressions"
"Find" box you put : `import a.b.c.d;`
"Replace with" box you put : `import e.f.g.h;\Rimport i.j.k.l;`
Then it will been replaced and separate line as you want.